# Работая в Сбере, мне не понравилось, но(,) работая в Тинькофф, мне понравилось

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Работая в Сбере, мне не понравилось, но(,) работая в Тинькофф, мне понравилось.`

Comment: These are incorrect suggestions! Who says so, where have you heard?

Comment: Лео, сочтёте ли вы эквивалентом Вашему вопросу такую фразу?  
"Работая в Сбере, я находился под неусыпным контролем и получал упреки за малейшие стилистические ошибки, но(,) перейдя в Тиньков, я ощутил все прелести полной свободы выражения своих мыслей".

Comment: Можно еще так:  Работать в Сбере мне не понравилось, а вот в "Тинькоффе"  нормально.   Стилевые особенности речи.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение неверное: деепричастный оборот **не может относиться** к личному местоимению **в косвенных падежах**, в данном случае к дательному.

Так что нужно заменить на придаточные:

***Когда я работал в Сбере, мне не понравилось, но, когда я работал в «Тинькофф», мне понравилось***.

После *но* запятая ставится, т. к. у придаточного, присоединяемого союзом *когда*, нет второй части (*когда..., тогда* — двухчастный союз; *когда* — одночастный)

---

А вот слово *Тинькофф* нужно закавычить. См. «Грамота.ру»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет. Здесь можно *но* с помощью *а* заменить. Здесь налицо противопоставление.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр От союза НО в вашем примере можно «оторвать» и переставить. А вот если замените на союз А, то переставить будет уже нельзя. Проверьте сами, увидите, что при союзе НО переставляется, а при союзе А нет.

Comment: These proposals cannot be discussed, Hermes Logius is angry with you!

Comment: @Sharon Вы кому?

Comment: Это я вам обоим!..  Нельзя говорит о правильности неправильных предложений. Неуважительное отношение к грамматике...

Comment: @Sharon А что не так?

Comment: Это еще хуже, чем у Чехова: Подъезжая к сией станции и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа.

Comment: @Sharon Ой... Извиняюсь за то, что не заметил эту ошибку! Получается, деепричастный оборот в таком предложении никак нельзя оставить? Только менять на придаточное?

Comment: Да, сделайте с ним  хотя бы что-нибудь, please.

Comment: I have never accepted correcting my sentences! My sentence is 100 percent understandable, and I didn't expect you, Sharon, to do such a horrible remark!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Если вы прям так хотите, то запятая нужна, я уже объяснил почему. От союза НО его можно «оторвать», а от союза А нельзя. Так что не надо их «склеивать»

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Your sentence, although understandable, is 100 percent wrong. // Просто замените "работая" на "работать", и всё будет ок.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Леопольда, как я понял, часто тянет на неверные слова/предложения, как то: _наикошеный_, _наиужасающий_ и, в конце концов, это предложение.

Comment: @Максим Лео ещё тот провокатор! Думаете, он не знал, что можно по-разному выделять буквы: А, *а*, "а", ***а***? Ему нужно было вставить в предложение слово "жопа". :)) // За исправление ответа, конечно, плюс, хотя с придаточным тоже не очень звучит: *что не понравилось?*

Comment: Я просто только на этой неделе узнать, что правильно писать *жопа*. Когда я об этом задумался, то подумал, что надо писать *жёпа*, ожидая, что оно от слова *жепяной* образовано. Вот и хотел вас, сэры мои совушки, предупредить об открытии.